# React Native WebView cache static html page

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React Native WebView cache static html page. I set a URL to html page in webview. Worked fine. But when I updated and deployed, the updated content is not shown in WebView in react native IOS app. When I directly to that URL using a browser I see the HTML is updated. Looks it is cache somewhere in the mobile. How do I avoid the cache? Only when I used the "reset content and setting" of the simulator, I see the updated content, otherwise it keep showing the old cached content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to clear the cache is `npm start --reset-cache` (specifically, however you invoke the RN server, pass the `--reset-cache` option to it).

If you are working on iOS platform and want to clear react-native cache then you may want to work with this package `react-native-http-cache`

```
$ npm install react-native-http-cache --save
```

See docs. [react-native-http-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-http-cache)

Comment: But how it will work when the app is installed in mobile? Will it always load the latest webpage?